# Retrieving Connection String when Creating ServiceBus with Pulumi (AzureNative)

Tags: c#, pulumi, pulumi-azure

I create a Servicebus-Namespace using AzureNative on Pulumi:

```
public void CreateNamespace(string namespaceName, SkuName skuname, SkuTier tier)
{
  var namespace = new Namespace(namespaceName, new NamespaceArgs
  {
    Location = _resourceGroup.Location,
    NamespaceName = namespaceName,
    ResourceGroupName = _resourceGroup.Name,
    Sku = new Pulumi.AzureNative.ServiceBus.Inputs.SBSkuArgs
    {
      Name = skuname,
      Tier = tier
    }
  });
}
```

The Servicebus Namespace is created correctly. After creating the Servicebus-Namespace I need to retrieve the ConnectionString for this resource. Either for the automatically created `RootManageSharedAccessKey` or alternatively by creating a specific additional policy for that task.

Within the Azure Portal I can retrieve the Key by navigating through
`Settings/Shared access policies/Policy/` and copying the Primary access key from there.

[image: Screenshot Azure Portal]

I did not find any property or function within the AzureNative.ServiceBus - Namespace that seem to lead to that key. Any way to retrieve that property?

Comment: Also trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new NamespaceRule and return ListNamespaceKeys-Properties:

```
var namespaceRule = new NamespaceAuthorizationRule(rulename, new NamespaceAuthorizationRuleArgs
{
  AuthorizationRuleName = rulename,
  NamespaceName = namespace.Name,
  ResourceGroupName = _resourceGroup.Name,
  Rights = new[]
  {
    AccessRights.Listen,
    AccessRights.Send
  }
});

var nameSpaceKeys = Output
.Tuple(namespace.Name, namespaceRule.Name)
.Apply(t => ListNamespaceKeys.InvokeAsync(new ListNamespaceKeysArgs
{
  NamespaceName = t.Item1,
  AuthorizationRuleName = t.Item2,
  ResourceGroupName = _resourceGroup.GetResourceName()
}));
```

Now NamespaceKeys contains all the required Properties like `PrimaryConnectionString` etc.